# NSZombie not logging to console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nszombie

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on one of my table views. I have tried adding the NSZombieEnabled key to the executables environment variables.

It seems to be working in that the screen no longer crashes, but I do not get any messages from the log to indicate what's going on

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the crash dump and your code where it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

NSZombieEnabled just catches crashes caused by over releasing objects but `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be caused by other issues. If you don't get a zombie warning, then the crash is arising from another source.

On a table, the most common cause would be getting the indexes of rows or sections wrong causing the table to ask data objects at non-existant locations in the data structure that provides the data to the table.

Comment: But it does stop crashing when I use NSZombieEnabled, so surely zombies are being made to "fix" the bug?

Answer (score 0):

as TechZen: pointed out, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` can be caused from other sources than over releasing objects (what you use `NSZombie` to check for essentially).  Try looking in the debugger and see what line the debugger stops on when you get the exception, because it can be any number of memory related issues (out of bounds errors, initialization, etc).